# hcclust, clustered observed correlation network data

Tags: r

I am new to R and Network theory. I would like to calculate the cluster correlation to investigate the structural equivalence of my data. I have been looking for a solution of the problem for quite some time now, also in this forum. I could find relevant contributions, but could not find out a solution for my problem.

The first note I should make is that I stacked directed network matrices on top of each other (one transposed and one not transposed for the directed network data). Following the structure http://www.imsbio.co.jp/RGM/R_rdfile?f=NetCluster/man/clusterCorr.Rd&d=R_CC

when I calculate

`clustered_observed_cors <- clustConfigurations(num_vertices, advice_m1_money_m1_kinship_m1_hclust, advice_m1_money_m1_kinship_m1_cors)`

the program stops and I cannot compute anything anymore until I hit the red stop button in the bottom left window of R Studio. That's my problem. does anyone have an idea what could be the reason for this being the case?

The error I get is

`In cor(as.vector(d[g1[i], , ]), as.vector(d[g2[j], , ]), use = "complete.obs") :
  the standard deviation is zero`

Any help appreciated,
Simon

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: This sounds like more than one problem. Suggest that you focus on the first error, make an example that reproduces in and get rid of all the other stuff. Then move on to the next problem. If the problem is lack of understanding of statistical method then first go to CrossValidated.com to resolve those steps. Voting to close (as too broad) in its current form, but I will reverse my vote if you edit along the lines I suggest.